# What locale does excel uses when you type ,F as date format?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, locale, date-format

My company builds reporting tools and one of the export formats is excel. As our customers come from different countries when we generate the excel file we use locale formatting to display the dates using the following formatter:

```
[$-<locale here>]mmmm d, yyyy;@
```

So if the cell has the date 31/03/2020 and locale is set to Ireland, it would display as March 10, 2020 but if locale is set Spain it will show Marzo 10, 2020

We received a customer report that it wasn't working for them as their 31/03/2020 date was being displayed as March 8, 2020

Upon closer inspection I noticed that their formatter was listed as:

```
[$-,F]mmmm d, yyyy;@
```

I've tried to find what is actually Excel trying to parse there or what calendar or date formatter is attempting to use to display that bogus date to not avail. We obviously need to do a better job at identifying the customer's locale, but I'm wondering if this could be caused by the customer having a weird locale in their computers or just some bogus code.

This happened in Excel 2013 but I was also able to reproduce it on Excel 365. I also attempted to locate any country code that was associated with the hex value of F not nothing worked. When the `,` is removed the formatter identifies F as the code for France and displays the correct date number in french: mars 30, 2020.

Comment: Hmm. France should be 040C according to [Specifying a Language for the TEXT Function (Microsoft Excel)](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T011782_Specifying_a_Language_for_the_TEXT_Function.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell `[$-,F]`, which is equivalent to `[$-F0000]` is converting the date into a lunar calendar.

I wanted to see what all the other letters represented in the same situation, so I wrote this:

```
Sub formatdates()


Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheet1

Dim i As Integer

i = 1

Do While i < 27

    ws.Cells(i, 1) = "=TODAY"
    ws.Cells(i, 1).NumberFormat = "[$-," & Chr(64 + i) & "]dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy"
    ws.Cells(i, 2) = "[$-," & Chr(64 + i) & "]dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy"
    ws.Cells(i, 3) = ws.Cells(i, 1).NumberFormat

i = i + 1

Loop


End Sub
```

You can use that in any empty workbook. It will display the current date using each of the letters in the Roman alphabet as a format code used similarly to the [$-,F] in your post. I'm sure there are more, but these were instructive enough to do a little digging.

For example

- [$-,F] will give you the Lunar calendar, but displayed in English, such that the fifth month is shown as June
- [$-,G] will give you the Indian Civil Calendar (I think)
- [$-,M] will give you the Persian Calendar (I think)
- [$-,N] will give you the Hijri Calendar

[image]

I also took the [list of language codes](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T011782_Specifying_a_Language_for_the_TEXT_Function.html) from the link that @DavidPostill included in his comment (there are [others out there with more complete lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191664/list-of-all-locales-and-their-short-codes) of country codes which can also be used, I think).

I put the table of codes from the link in the comment above into Sheet2 and wrote this to append to the bottom of the table created with the first function above, just out of interest.

```
Sub formatdates2()


Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheet1

Dim i As Integer
Dim r As Integer

r = 1

i = 28

Do While Sheet2.Cells(r, 1) <> ""

    ws.Cells(i, 1) = "=TODAY()"
    ws.Cells(i, 1).NumberFormat = "[$-" & Sheet2.Cells(r, 1) & "]dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy"
    ws.Cells(i, 2) = "[$-," & Sheet2.Cells(r, 1) & "]dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy"
    ws.Cells(i, 3) = ws.Cells(i, 1).NumberFormat
    ws.Cells(i, 4) = Sheet2.Cells(r, 2)

i = i + 1
r = r + 1

Loop


End Sub
```

As far as I can tell, there are language codes (the latter list/function) and there are calendar codes (the former function).

I think you are looking for language codes.

But you might have more success in simply using `[$-x-sysdate]`, which is the code shown when I select the required format from the list under "Date" in the Format Cells dialog and then view the same in the "Custom" list.

[image]

Comment: That was brilliant. Thanks a million for sharing the code for this.